# How to get users group by date and user info using laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get following data from table

- Count of registered users in each date
- User details

I am trying following script to get that

```
$users = User::select(DB::raw('count(id) as agents, left(DATE(created_at),10) as registeredDate'))
->whereHas('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('name', '=', 'agent');
})
->offset($start)
->limit($limit)
->orderBy($order,'DESC')
->groupBy('registeredDate')
->get();
```

Above query is returning the Count of registered users in each date

```
if($users){
    foreach($users as $r){
        $nestedData['agents'] = $r->agents;
        $nestedData['date'] = date('d M Y',strtotime($r->registeredDate));
        $data[] = $nestedData;
    }
}
```

But I wanted to get users details also in the same query. My desired output is

```
'data' => [
    [
        "agents" => "13",
        "date" => "12 Jan 2019",
        "nested_data" => [
        [
            'full_name' => 'john',
            'status' => 'active',
            'email' => 'john@gmail.com',
        ],
        [
            'full_name' => 'John',
            'status' => 'active',
            'email' => 'john2@gmail.com',
        ]
        ]
    ]

]
```

Can someone kindly guide me how to achieve it. I would like to appreciate. Thanks

Comment: You cannot get all user data e.g. full_name with a query contains groupBy().

Comment: You may get all rows, which is required because of the fields like full_name and status, and build the array with foreach, and assign the counts of the groups

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as:

```
$users = User::select(DB::raw('count(id) as agents, left(DATE(created_at),10) as registeredDate'))
->whereHas('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('name', '=', 'agent');
})
->offset($start)
->limit($limit)
->orderBy($order,'DESC')
->get();
```

Change your foreach loop as:

```
if($users){
    foreach($users as $user){
        $date = date('d M Y',strtotime($r->registeredDate));
        $data[$date]['date'] = $date;
        $data[$date]['nestedData'][] = ['first_name' => $user->first_name, 'status' => $user->status, 'email' => $user->email];
        $data[$date]['agents'] = count($data[$date]['nestedData']);
    }
}
```